# Rest assured Collection issue

Tags: rest-assured

Below is code

```
given().
        get("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all").        
then().
      body("RestResponse.result.name", hasItems("Austria","Algeria")).log().all();
```

hasItems() is not recognized by IDE, showing as can't resolve method hasItems()

Maven dependecies exist:  Rest assured, groovy, hamcrest.

please help me.

Comment: Maybe post what error / stacktrace you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned you have it included in your POM Dependancies, but have you tried having the library imported?

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

The request you made is perfect and I don't see any issues in it. I understood that method 'hasItems' is not resolved in Eclipse. Means, it wasn't properly imported in IDE.

Add import like below:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.hasItems;
```

which solves your issue.